# Is there any way to enable scrolling with XP Pen?

Tags: mac, macos, ventura

I have XP-Pen Deco 01 V2. Things have been so great using on Mac(v13.1).

But, on drag (dragging pen on the tablet) it doesn't scroll the page but behaves as touch-and-hold.

While on windows, things work well; it does the scrolling.

Is there any way I could change this behaviour on mac and enable scrolling with the pen when dragging on the tablet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally found a way to make this work:

1. Set the button you like to "mouse control > middle click"
2. Set up *something* that can turn a middle click + drag into scrolling. What worked for me was using [hammerspoon](https://hammerspoon.org) and the script outlined in https://superuser.com/questions/303424/can-i-enable-scrolling-with-middle-button-drag-in-os-x